Pandas dataframe - finding row comparing two cell values
I have a dataframe:
Email                | ... | Name
--------------------------------------
john.cena@gmail.com  | ... | John Cena
john.smith@gmail.com | ... | John Cena

I need to find a row, that matches Name column with Email column when
email_cell.split("@")[0] == name_cell.lower().replace(" ", ".")

I tried dataframe.loc[dataframe["Email"].str.contains(dataframe["Name"].replace(" ", "."))]  and other ways but I cannot use Series as if it was a string.
Is there a way to do this?

Take email usernames by splitting on '@' and Convert names to lowercase and replaces spaces with dots
df[df['Email'].str.split('@').str[0] == df['Name'].str.lower().str.replace(' ', '.')]

Output
Matched rows:
                   Email         Name
0    john.cena@gmail.com    John Cena
2  randy.orton@gmail.com  Randy Orton

You can also try apply with lambda
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Email'].split('@')[0] == x['Name'].lower().replace(' ', '.'), axis=1)]


You can define the condition and apply row by row
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Email'].split('@')[0] == row['Name'].lower().replace(' ', '.'), axis=1)
matching_rows = df[df['match']]

Output
              Email       Name  match
0  john.cena@gmail.com  John Cena   True

